# Pyspark: add one row dynamically into the final dataframe

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I've a final dataframe with this format:

- Product_ID: string
- Product_COD: string
- Product_NAM: string
- Product_VER: integer
- ProductLine_NAM: string
- Language_COD: string
- ProductType_NAM: string
- Load_DAT: integer
- LoadEnd_DAT:integer
- edmChange_DTT: timestamp

and I want to add a new row to that dataframe where the ID (Product_ID) is -1 and in the string columns insert 'Unknown' and in the remaining datatypes set to "null" for example:

[image]

I created this code:

```
id_column = "Product_ID"
df_lessOne = spark.createDataFrame(["-1"], "string").toDF(id_column) #create a new id_column row with -1

appended_df = finalDf.unionByName(df_lessOne, allowMissingColumns=True) #add the rest columns of dataframe with nulls

appended_df_filter = appended_df.filter(""+ id_column + " = '-1'")

columns = [item[0] for item in appended_df_filter.dtypes if item[1].startswith('string')] #select only string columns

# replace string columns with "Unknown" 
for c_na in columns:
    appended_df_filter = (appended_df_filter
                               .filter(""+ id_column + " = '-1'")
                               .withColumn(c_na, lit('Unknown'))
                         )
                          
appended_df = appended_df.filter(""+ id_column + " <> '-1'")

dfs = [appended_df, appended_df_filter]

#add final -1 row to the final dataframe
finalDf = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)

display(finalDf)
```

but unfortunately, it's not working well.

I'm trying to create this dynamically because after I want to use it in other dataframes. I just need to change the id_column after.

Can anyone please help me in achieving this

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from datetime import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data2 = [
    ("xp3980","2103","Product_1",1,"PdLine_23","XX1","PNT_1",2,36636,datetime.strptime('2020-08-20 10:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
    ("gi9387","2411","Product_2",1,"PdLine_44","YT89","PNT_6",2,35847,datetime.strptime('2021-07-21 7:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("Product_ID",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("Product_COD",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("Product_NAM",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("Product_VER", IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("ProductLine_NAM", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Language_COD", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("ProductType_NAM", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Load_DAT", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("LoadEnd_DAT", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("edmChange_DTT", TimestampType(), True) \
  ])
 
my_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)

df_res = spark.createDataFrame([(-1,)]).toDF("Product_ID")

for c in my_df.schema:
    if str(c.name) == 'Product_ID':
        continue
    if str(c.dataType) == 'StringType':
        df_res = df_res.withColumn(c.name, F.lit('Unknown'))
    else:
        df_res = df_res.withColumn(c.name, F.lit(None))

my_df.union(df_res).show()

+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------------+---------------+--------+-----------+-------------------+
# |Product_ID|Product_COD|Product_NAM|Product_VER|ProductLine_NAM|Language_COD|ProductType_NAM|Load_DAT|LoadEnd_DAT|      edmChange_DTT|
# +----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------------+---------------+--------+-----------+-------------------+
# |    xp3980|       2103|  Product_1|          1|      PdLine_23|         XX1|          PNT_1|       2|      36636|2020-08-20 10:00:00|
# |    gi9387|       2411|  Product_2|          1|      PdLine_44|        YT89|          PNT_6|       2|      35847|2021-07-21 07:00:00|
# |        -1|    Unknown|    Unknown|       null|        Unknown|     Unknown|        Unknown|    null|       null|               null|
# +----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------------+---------------+--------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Luiz, it is working well :) !!!!